# Replace zero values in vector

Tags: matlab

Ive got a vector like this

```
a=[0 5 3 0 1]
```

and a corresponding vector, containing the same amount of numbers as there are zeros in the first vector

```
b=[2 4]
```

what I want to get is

```
x=[2 5 3 4 1]
```

I tried fiddling around with, and somewhat got the feeling that the find / full methods might help me here, but didn't get it to work

```
c=(a==0) 
>[1 0 0 1 0]
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is as easy as this:

```
x=a;
```

As `x==0` gives the vector of all the locations an element = 0, ie [0 1 0 0 1], `x(x==0)` is indexing x to get the actual elements of x that are equal to 0, which you can then assign values as if it were any other vector/matrix (where the values we are not interested in do not exist, and are not indexed), using the following:

```
x(x==0)=b;
```

Comment: Or even shorter `a(~a)=b` =)

Comment: @RobertP. That would overwite the values of `a`, which OP does not want to do